# Programar un nueva tarea o trabajo en SQL Server Management Studio con base de datos Windows Azure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-storage

En versiones anteriores de `SQL Server Management Studio` en cuestión la versión 2008 r2 , se podía crear tarea o trabajos como se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la versión actual de `SQL Server Management Studio` 2019 cuando me conecto a mi base en windows azure, no veo la opción de poder realizar esto, si alguien me podría guiar para poder saber como implementar este tipo de tarea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El agente de SQL Server (o también llamado SQL Server Agent) no está disponible en Azure SQL Database, solamente está disponible en Azure SQL Managed Instance.

Para Azure SQL Database usted puede usar [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/automation/) para programar/automatizar la ejecución de procedimientos almacenados (stored procedures) y otras tareas como se muestra en [este tutorial](https://5minutebi.com/2018/02/08/sql-azure-stored-procedure-automation-using-runbooks-email/).